# Determine reference for reference-compressed SRA file

Tags: file-formats, fastq, format-conversion, sratoolkit

*Note: this question was also asked on [Github](https://github.com/ncbi/sra-tools/issues/202).*

I have 241 SRA files that appear to be reference compressed. I didn't even know this was a thing until I tried to convert them to Fastq files without an internet connection. I got the "name not found while resolving..." error described at the bottom of [this page](https://ncbi.github.io/sra-tools/fastq-dump.html) when I attempted to do the conversion.

The instructions say:

> *If you have elected to prevent the toolkit from contacting NCBI, you will need to manually acquire the reference(s) here*

We have many NCBI databases mirrored locally, including RefSeq, so it's likely that we already have all the references. I have two questions:

- How do I determine the reference used to compress a reference-compressed SRA file? (Note this needs to be scripted for 241 SRA files, so manual inspection is out of the question.)
- Once I've determined the correct reference and ensured it is available locally, how to I tell `fastq-dump` where to find it?

Answer (score 1):

Run align-info  to see the references used.
Run prefetch </path/to/sra/file> to download missed references.